# Enigma of Blogger Font Sizes

Tags: fonts

In the two articles linked below the font-size is the same, yet the font appears larger and more widely spaced in the first one. Both use the font Georgia, a line-height of 1.4., a font-size of 110% as defined for the post-body, and a font of 15px as defined for the body.

http://www.eurocanadian.ca/2014/11/bruce-bawer-for-destruction-of-european.html
http://www.eurocanadian.ca/2014/11/bruce-bawer-for-destruction-of-european_5.html

I would like to display both articles like the first. Throughout the blog are several articles affected by this font issues.

I am also vexed by the command line .post-body { font-size: 110%; ... I thought the percentages were just another way to determine the size of the font instead of pixels and was on my way to delete it as redundant. But playing around with the percentages I found out that they rather determine the spacing between the lines; at 140% it is much increased.

Now am I useless with CSS and HTML or am I right that Blogger is just plain shoddy when it comes to keeping uniform font sizes?

Before you ask, Blogger even behaved fickle with font sizes when I typed in the text into the edit window, not just only with imported Word documents.

Comment: I looked at both articles.  One uses a serif font, the other a sans serif font; they definitely aren't the same font.  All of the character dimensions and spacing characteristics can be different between different fonts of the same point size.  Maybe the question to ask is why they appear to be the same font on your system.

Comment: @fixer1234 They do have the same font, Georgia. I defined Georgia as default font: *Variable name="body.font" description="Font" type="font" default="normal normal 12px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 15px Georgia, Open Sans, Arial"* Although the font of the first article (Part II) is at the same time defined as *span style="font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;"*, my Firefox "inspect element" says this command is being suppressed (displayed as struck out) in favour of the default mode.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts, possibly by using an unregistered account across multiple devices. You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" to have your accounts merged. In order to merge them you will need to provide links to the two accounts, for your information these are http://superuser.com/users/387158/teddy-savalas and http://superuser.com/users/387294/teddy-savalas. You'll then be able to edit, comment on and accept answers to this question.

Comment: The issue isn't that the same font is appearing differently.  Two different fonts are being used despite your setting them to be the same.  One appears on my system as a serif font.  The problem to diagnose is why your settings are not being used.  Look for something like an additional, conflicting setting.  Perhaps compare both sources using a file comparison tool that highlights differences.